# youtube video id from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have obtained these codes from other stackoverflow pages to correct youtube links but they dont work for my url:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2dRQHJ-aAk
```

code:

```
<script>
$('#videoURL').focusout(function() {
    var url = this.value;
    var videoid = url.match(/(?:https?:\/{2})?(?:w{3}\.)?youtu(?:be)?\.(?:com|be)(?:\/watch\?v=|\/)([^\s&]+)/);
    if(videoid != null) {
      $('#videoURL').value('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+videoid[1]);
    } else { 
        console.log("The youtube url is not valid.");
    }
});

</script>
```

it always returns:

> The youtube url is not valid

Comment: the video id is always 11 characters long, and can only be `a-zA-Z0-9` `-` and `_`. Just search the given string for a collection of characters that match that.

Comment: so which part should i modify?

Comment: Seems to be working as it is: http://jsfiddle.net/3JCHb/

Comment: no it is not the same question, coz user is allowed to enter none youtube urls and code should recognize that.

Comment: @hjpotter92 doesn't always work: http://jsfiddle.net/3JCHb/1/

Comment: @hjpotter92, tnx, works like charm

Comment: @hjpotter92, where was the problem? it didnt work on my firefox browser

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a regular expression for this:

```
var videoid = url.split('v=')[1];
var ampersandPosition = videoid.indexOf('&');
if(ampersandPosition != -1) {
    videoid = video_id.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
}
```

You can use it if you want however:

```
var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(https?://(www\.)?)?youtube\.com/watch\?v=([0-9a-zA-Z\-]{11})$
```

Works for;

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2dRQHJ-aAk
https://youtube.com/watch?v=r2dRQHJ-aAk
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2dRQHJ-aAk
youtube.com/watch?v=r2dRQHJ-aAk
```

I'm unsure about other youtube url formats, but you should be able to extract it with subgroup 3.

Answer (score 0):

in fact I had done a mistake:

```
var url = this.value;
```

should change into:

```
var url = this.val();
```

thanks to @hjpotter92